# indirecting integer in bash

Tags: bash

I have a bash script which contains following function:

```
random_move() {
  local sq
  while :; do
    sq=$(( $RANDOM % $# + 1 ))
    sq=${!sq}
    [ $sq -ne ${last:-666} ] && break
  done
  move "$sq"
}
```

This function is called with one or more arguments. What is the point of indirection(`sq=${!sq}` line) there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, $sq is assigned a random number from one to the number of arguments of the function. Then, the sq-th argument is assigned to it by the indirection. E.g., if `sq=4`, then `${!sq}` means `${4}`, i.e. `$4`.

Also, the value of $last (or 666 if not set) is never "moved", if it's selected, the loop doesn't stop and another value is generated.